# Getting hardcoded value from input tag into angular controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angularjs in my application.I am trying to pass hardcoded value from input tag into angularjs controller.Here i am not taking any dynamic values.User just clicks the input area.Based on clicked area i am passing value into angular controller.

Here is my html

```
    <div class="first-hour">
    <input type="text" value="12:00am - 12:30am" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="second-hour">
    <input type="text" value="12:30am - 01:00am" readonly>
    </div>
```

If the user select first input text box value is 12:00am - 12:30am and if second means value is 12:30am - 01:00am.I need to get these values inside angular controller.Can anyone tell how to get the input hardcoded values directly into angularjs controller?

Comment: You are thinking backwards with AngularJS, [Don't design your page, and then change it with DOM manipulations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/8495123)

Comment: I need to pass the value based on selected input field.The values i need to assign to each input field and pass it to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can select a specific filed. Both ranges have to be initialised in the Controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.range1 = "12:00am - 12:30am";
  $scope.range2 = "12:30am - 01:00am";

  $scope.select = function(val) {
    $scope.display = angular.copy(val);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="first-hour">
    <input type="text" ng-model="range1" ng-click="select(range1)" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="second-hour">
    <input type="text" ng-model="range2" ng-click="select(range2)" readonly>
  </div>
  Selected: {{display}}
</div>
```

(`value` was replaced with `ng-model`)

Comment: If i give ng-model it displays the values.I dont want to display values in input field.I just want to get the values after clicking the field

Comment: @SachinHR your example would also display the values, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,
create one object and initialize value in controller itself. then bind the object in html,

```
$scope.client = {};
$scope.client.start = "12:00am - 12:30am";
```

in html page,

```
<div class="first-hour">
    <input type="text" ng-model="client.start" readonly>
</div>
```

please let me know if u have any quires.

Comment: If i give ng-model it displays the values.I dont want to display values in input field.I just want to get the values after clicking the field